# sftp ssh tunneling and Nautilus (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ssh, nautilus, tunnel

I have a problem with sftp connection via ssh tunnel and use of Nautilus to watch the file inside. If I launch by terminal the command

```
ssh -t -X BASTIONHOST sftp SERVER
```

he ask me the password of BastionHost and then the password of server. And so, the login was successfully.

How can I do the same thing from Nautilus (Ubuntu 20.04)?

I've tried some configuration adding ./ssh/config

```
Host bastion
    Hostname bastionhost.host.ip
    User userbastion
    Port 22

Host server
    Hostname serverhost.host.ip
    User userserver
    ProxyCommand ssh bastion
```

but never works. If I put in Nautilus command "sftp://server", he ask me the Bastion Host credential but nothing more, connection end cause timeout. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the protocol SSHFS. It use SSH and SFTP but with this protocol you can mount a remote HardDisk or SSD.
`sudo apt install sshfs`
To manage this you need to open ssh port and in the client digit:

`sudo sshfs -o allow_other your_username@192.168.1.5:/where/your_ssd/is_mount /where/you_want/to_mount`

`sshfs` is the protocol
`-o allow_other` is necessary for ubuntu system.
`username@ip_addres` where the real Hardisk or SSD is mount.
`:/where/your_ssd/is_mount`  the server point of mount
`/where/you_want/to_mount`  the client point of mount